# A recurrence relation $ x_{k+1}=\alpha x_k+ \beta x_{k-1}$ with $ \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_k=a $

Tags: sequences-and-series

A three-term recurrence relation with constant coefficients between real numbers is defined, in general, as follows
$$
x_{k+1}=\alpha x_k+ \beta x_{k-1}
$$
where $\alpha, \beta\in \mathbb{R}$.
We determine the generic term $x_k$, knowing that $x_0=p, x_1=q$, where $p,q\in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
x_k=\frac{q-\frac{p}{2}(\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\beta})}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\beta}}\left[\frac{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\beta}}{2}\right]^k+ \left(p-\frac{q-\frac{p}{2}(\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\beta})}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\beta}}\right)\left[\frac{\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\beta}}{2}\right]^k
$$
As we can guess from the picture:
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_k=a
$$
My request is as follows: after setting $a$, determining at least one choice of $p,q,\alpha,\beta$ such that
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_k=a
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$p=q=a\qquad\alpha=1/\mathrm e\qquad\beta=1-1/\mathrm e$$

Comment: Is $e$ Neper number?

Comment: Yes. But you may replace it by $\pi/4$ if you wish.

Comment: $\beta=1-\alpha$...

Comment: Yeah, alpha=pi/4 and beta=1-pi/4, as long as alpha+beta=1. What are you trying to say?

Comment: I tried a Fibonacci sequence, the interval $(0, a)$, which converge to $a$ (starting from the neighborhood of 0). But now I realize that this is not possible, unless we consider $\alpha=1-\beta$ as in cases where the general term $x_k$ is constant.